# What driver supports keyboard light in HP Envy?

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I have an HP Envy notebook. the keyboard light is not working. I have tried all the key combinations for turning on the backlight, but none has been able to turn on the backlight.

When I visited the HP support website, there were three drivers under the keyboard and mouse category. The details for the three drivers were not supporting keyboard light. so I decided to download one of them; synaptics touchpad driver, for a try.

After installing the driver, my keyboard light is still not functional.

I would like to know the driver that supports keyboard backlight for HP Envy notebook.

Comment: There are a few dozens of HP Envy models. Which model do you have?

Comment: What Windows is installed? 7,8,10?

Comment: It should be the "System Event Utility" also check bios to be sure action keys are enabled.

Comment: my model is HP ENVY 15-k058ca Notebook PC (ENERGY STAR). The windows installed is windows 10.

Comment: how do i check bios